# Configure Broadcast domain in Linux

Tags: linux, mac-address, broadcast

In Linux, how can I see all MAC addresses present in a broadcast domain, and how can I configure a broadcast domain?

Comment: Did you try `man arp`?

Comment: man arp is a huge beast. Is there anything specific you can point me to.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all MAC addresses present in a broadcast domain by executing the following command :-

```
nmap -sP 172.18.72.0/24
```

for more help run

```
nmap --help
```

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast domain is a logical division of a computer network, in which all nodes can reach each other by broadcast at the data link layer. A broadcast domain can be within the same LAN segment or it can be bridged to other LAN segments.

In terms of current popular technologies: Any computer connected to the same Ethernet repeater or switch is a member of the same broadcast domain. Further, any computer connected to the same set of inter-connected switches/repeaters is a member of the same broadcast domain. Routers and other higher-layer devices form boundaries between broadcast domains.

So you couldn't configure broadcast domain on your Machine, but you can found all machines using `arp` or `nmap` as mentioned in previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, I was asking if I can create virtual VLANs in Linux such that I can place different interfaces in separate broadcast domains.

Comment: You can configure subinterfaces. here [simple article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html) how to do it.